# How can the index.html file be served from a sub directory of the DocumentRoot without using system level links?

Tags: url, apache2, virtualhost, configuration, document-root

How can the *index.html* file be served from a sub directory of the `DocumentRoot` without using system level links?

For example:

- Let the document root of an apache 2.4 virtual host be `dirA`
- Let the the base url (VirtualHost) be `http://test.local/`
- Let index.html reside in `dirA/dirB/`
- Let `http://test.local/` (the base URL) resolve the *index.html* file (not give a listing of directories).

I've been attempting to use mod rewrite to do this but am unfamiliar with regex and with mod rewrite. The rule I have that works is `RewriteRule . /html/index.html [L]`  but this is unacceptable since any URL will resolve to test.local/html/  (where the *index.html* file lives).

What is needed is for the exact URL corresponds to the document root find the *index.html* file in a sub directory of the document root (namely "html") instead of the document root --without using system level symbolic linking (ie: entirely from within Apache).

Answer (score 2):

You may want the mod_rewrite solution that @Stephen suggests, however, also consider `DirectoryIndex` (depending on your requirements).

The `DirectoryIndex` document tells Apache which file to serve when you request a directory. This often defaults to `index.html` in the directory being requested, however, you can specify any file, anywhere. For example:

```
DirectoryIndex /html/index.html
```

This instructs Apache to serve the root-relative `/html/index.html` file when requesting any directory (eg. the document root, as in your case). If you wanted to serve `index.html` in the requested directory when it exists, but `/html/index.html` otherwise, then you can include both, in the order that they should be tested, for example:

```
DirectoryIndex index.html /html/index.html
```

Reference:
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dir.html#directoryindex

Answer (score 1):

Your rewrite rule is close.   You just need to restrict it a bit more.

```
RewriteRule ^\/?$ /html/index.html [L]
```

The `\/` matches a literal slash, which is the desired URL for the home page. It is escaped with the backslash.

The question mark makes the slash optional so that the rule can be used in either *.htaccess* or inside an Apache *.conf* file.

The `^` matches the start of the URL path and the `$` matches the end of the URL path.  Putting those on will restrict the rule to just the home page.

If you want to rewrite all `.html` files to that subdirectory, you could also add the rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/html/
RewriteRule ^\/?(.*\.html)$ /html/$1 [L]
```

Comment: "It is escaped with the backslash." - Although there's no need to backslash escape the literal slash here.

Comment: Oh, your last `RewriteRule` would actually result in a rewrite loop (eg. `/html/html/html/foo.html` etc.)

Comment: Good catch @MrWhite.   I added a RewriteCond to prevent that.   I thought the `[L]` flag might prevent it from being re-evaluated.